# Check a param,cookie defined against a method is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code that is working to assign a locale based first on a param, then a previously set cookie and then by requesting the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.

```
def set_locale
  if params[:locale] 
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  elsif cookies[:locale]
    I18n.locale = cookies[:locale]
  else 
    I18n.locale = sanitizeLocale(request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]) # e.g. "en,es;q=0.8,de-de;q=0.5,en-us;q=0.3"
  end
  cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale
end

def sanitizeLocale(locale)
  @locale, lang_weight = cookies[:locale] || begin
    if accept_lang = request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] # e.g. "en,es;q=0.8,de-de;q=0.5,en-us;q=0.3"
      accept_lang.to_s.split(',').collect {|l| x,y = l.split(';q='); [x.split('-').first, (y||1).to_f]}.sort_by(&:last).reverse.find {|lang, lang_weight| %w[es en it fr de].include?(lang)}
      # returns ["en", 1.0]
    end
  end || 'en' # default
  return @locale
end
```

My question is how can I check both the `params[:locale]` given and `cookies[:locale]` against the `sanitizeLocale`. I'm interesting in only get a valid value such as `es en it fr de` or default to en based on the input.

I been trying to just pass its values to `sanitizeLocale` similarly I'm doing for `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`  for some reason I can't understand is not working and is always defaulting to `en` even when `params[:locale]` given values are valid like `it`.

Comment: So you want to look at `params` and `cookies` and then check what you get from there against the `Accept-Language` stuff in `sanitizeLocale`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can simplify your Accept-Language parsing a bit:

```
def acceptable_langs
  extract_langs = lambda do |l|
    x, y = l.split(';q=')
    [x.split('-').first, -(y || 1).to_f] # the -1 makes sort_by nicer
  end
  known_langs = lambda { |lang| %w[es en it fr de].include?(lang.first) }
  quality = :last
  language = :first
  langs = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].to_s
                 .split(',')
                 .map(&extract_langs)
                 .select(&known_langs)
                 .sort_by(&quality)
                 .collect(&:language)
  langs + ['en']
end
```

The `to_s` will take care of `nil`s and the lambdas and extra variables are just there to clarify the logic. You don't have to do this, all you really need is a method that returns the language codes that are acceptable to both the user and your software ordered by the user's preference.

Now back to `set_locale`. You say that you need the language to match Accept-Langauge (with `'en'` as a fallback) regardless of what the URL or cookies have to say. That means that you have to parse Accept-Language no matter what and then check `params[:locale]` and `cookies[:locale]` against that list:

```
def set_locale
  # Figure out what they're asking for with English as the
  # default. Note that `acceptable_langs` always forces English
  # to be in the list.
  asking_for = params[:locale] || cookies[:locale] || 'en'

  # acceptable_langs is always in preference order so we just
  # want the first one that matches our `lang`.
  lang = acceptable_langs.find { |lang| asking_for == lang }

  # Now we have an acceptable language in `lang` (thanks to all
  # the `'en'` fallbacks we sprinkled about).
  I18n.locale = cookies[:locale] = lang
end
```

You could also add a little "I've already done all this work" flag to the cookies so that you could simply trust `cookies[:locale]` if the flag is set; there's probably no reason to prematurely optimize `set_locale` though.